# Python inter-process communication, getting pid of an independent process (not child) started from another Python process

Tags: python, process, communication, pid

I have a problem that feels like it ought to be simple. As a side-note, I'm already using the `multiprocessing` module, so I'm somewhat reluctant to use the `subprocess` module. Anyway, I have a Python program, `foo.py`, that starts another Python program `bar.py` through the `os.system()` function.

```
os.system("start python bar.py")
```

For other complicated reasons, this has to be done this way, as opposed to starting some sort of child process. The problem is, I would like to know the pid of `bar.py`. What is the most elegant or efficient way of doing this? At the moment I'm getting around this problem by using `bar.py` to write its pid into a temporary file for `foo.py` to read, but I feel there must be a better way.

By the way, obviously it's easy for `bar.py` to know the pid of `foo.py`, because `foo.py` can pass it in as a command-line argument using `os.system`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

multiprocessing != subprocess

You can still use subprocess in multiprocessing, instead of os.system('...') and get what you need by typing ".pid" on your Popen object.

As you can see [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system), subprocess can (and you should use it!) replace os.system.

In your case, you need the process ID, so you can create a Popen object, like in the examples found [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-popen-os-popen2-os-popen3).
Then let's write some lines of code:

```
import subprocess
args = ['/path/to/python', 'bar.py']
process = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=True, creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE) # you can also set only shell=True
print process.pid
```

Comment: I know that `multiprocessing` != `subprocess`, that's exactly what I'm saying. Given that I'm using `multiprocessing`, I'm reluctant to use `subprocess`. Could you expand on "typing `.pid`" and `Popen`? I've never used `subprocess` before.

Comment: Thanks Markon. The difference between `os.system()` and `subprocess.Popen()`, it seems, is the following. My command shown in my question will open a new command prompt window (in Windows) and run `bar.py` in that new window, which is what I need. Your `process = subprocess.Popen(args)` command will run `bar.py` in the same window. How do I run `bar.py` in a separate window using `subprocess`?

Comment: set creationFlags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE inside the Popen constructor. (you could also use shell=True)

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem! Though 2 things:

1. `shell=True` does not work for me. Perhaps it only works on Linux?
2. It's not `creationFlags`, but `creationflags`.

Thanks again Markon! Perhaps edit your post to change `creationFlags` to `creationflags` in case other people read this?

Comment: Ops! However, that's strange because if you read the doc, it says: "This flag is always set when Popen is created with shell=True." Bha.. mmh However I'm glad it worked for you :)